# jpackage seems to pack things it shouldn't

Tags: java, jlink, jpackage

I'm trying to create a native installer using jpackage for a relatively small program. The created app image is ~120 MB in size. This is odd since I used jlink before and the runtime image only used to be ~40 MB. After some digging, I found `runtime/lib/modules` in my app image, a file 90 MB in size. As `runtime/legal` lists a lot of things (modules?) I don't use, I think that jpackage packs things it shouldn't, but I'm not sure.

Note: The program isn't supposed to be modular. My understanding is that this is only useful when making multi-part programs or libraries. I used the `module-info.java` that was autocreated by eclipse to, well, "trick" jlink into creating a runtime image.

Here are the args I use to create the app image.

```
--type app-image
--name myapp
--dest target\appimg
--temp target\appimg-work
--input target\jar
--icon .\icon.ico
--main-jar target\jar\myapp.jar
--main-class com.msgprograms.myapp.AppMain
```

After copying some files into the app image, I create the installer using another jpackage run, this time using these args:

```
--type msi
--app-version 0.0.1
--copyright "(C) msgprograms"
--description "some app"
--name myapp
--dest target
--temp target\installer-work
--vendor msg-programs
--app-image target\appimg\myapp
// omitted windows-specific args
```

Why is the app image so big and how do I make it smaller? Is there a way other than making the program modular again, creating a runtime image with jlink and then giving that to jpackage?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the app doesn't use JavaFX. All articles I found on jpackage do though, so they're of limited help only.

EDIT 2:
Trying to be clever by doing `--jlinkoptions "--add-modules java.desktop"` doesn't work, as `jlink option [--add-modules] is not permitted in --jlink-options`

Comment: FWIW, to find out which modules were included in the runtime, you could use `runtime/bin/java --list-modules`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that one!

Answer (score 2):

JPackage does automatically use jlink to build a JRE, and those modules end up in that modules file. If your jar isn't modular then jpackage will be adding everything unless you set `--add-modules`. Otherwise check `module-info.java`only contains the essentials for your runtime, not any test code dependencies. Some versions of Eclipse I've used have been very keen to add JUNIT test libraries to `module-info.java` which are not required in the deployment release directories. Eclipse should be set up with separated build directories for src + test code.

However there are benefits to using `jlink` independently as you can test your codebase with the JRE before using jpackage - this can save a lot of time and if your JDK dependencies are not changing the previously `jlink` JRE is already prepared.

Also, the jlink command line supports addition flags to strip down the JRE size further:

```
jlink --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --compress=1 --add-modules blah,blah  --output myjre
```

Comment: I don't have a `module-info.java`, since I thought "if I can specify a non-modular program jpackage probably does some magic to only pack what's needed"... Seems like it doesn't, it just packs everything. Seems like I have to mess with modules again :(

Comment: Minor addition to your answer: jpackage runs jlink with --strip-debug, --no-header-files, --no-man-pages, and  --strip-native-commands by default.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial. https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX It's also primarily made for JavaFX but the basic principles are general and would be helpful for you. It separates the jlink phase from the jpackage phase and thus makes it possible to completely avoid the module system but still be able to build a reduced runtime image.

Comment: Very interesting as this uses maven, as my project does. I'd found something similar (https://github.com/wiverson/maven-jpackage-template) which I've modified to do two jpackage runs instead. This is still good to know about though. Thanks!