# Java FX Application with Jpackage not work

Tags: java, jpackage

I've created my Application in JavaFX.  Everything works well, so I use the Jpackage to make a installable version of my application in Window.

After I install the package, the window computer still ask to install JVM.

```
jpackage -t exe --name "FReport" --description "Time reporting" --app-version 1.0 --input "C:\myapp" --dest "C:\myapp\out" --main-jar "freport.jar" --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --win-shortcut --win-menu
```

My expectation, that I can use Jpackage to install my JavaFX application on any computer and it automatically setup the JVM ..etc.  The user just have to click on the icon and run the application.

Any suggestion on the correct command in Jpackage to pack my JavaFX application jar file with all the require environment like JVM ..etc

Comment: What command did you use? What was the output?

Comment: Just update the ticket with command.

Comment: I was disappointed with lack of support for Java packages.  I’m re-writing my application in C#

Comment: Jpackage definitely works with JavaFX - see amendment to my answer. if that does not help you need to add more details to the question on exact errors you see.

Answer (score 4):

You have not specified the correct modules for JavaFX - you have referenced the lib files not modules so `jlink` won't contain the JavaFX libraries because it does not read the modules such as `javafx.base.jmod`. Download jmods JDK and reference `C:\somepath\javafx-jmods-VER` instead of the lib release.

Additionally: turn on console by adding `--win-console` and report back what the actual error messages are when your run the installer and the application EXEs.

You have specified `--input` with nested `--dest` inside, so you will get your whole application copied into the second release

Test your application with the installed runtime image, or as separate image (see below). Simply reference the installer location of `jlink` runtime with your current application to see which modules are missing.

If you don't update `-app-version` each time then the new package is NOT installed by any of the subsequent attempts unless you un-install the previous installation. This is very frustrating, jpackage ought to warn on re-install same version rather than give up with no error message.

Note all of these other typical `jpackage` issues:

- [Enable console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606900/in-java-how-do-you-debug-exe-created-by-jpackage)
- [update version number each run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675323/cannot-rerun-java-jpackage-installer-if-already-installed-second-time-just-exit)
- [minimise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69514293/jpackage-seems-to-pack-things-it-shouldnt)
- [use manual jlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) to create JavaFX JRE, then you can test the JRE before running `jpackage`