# Creating an installer with Java-17 JPackage

Tags: java, javafx, package, modular, jpackage

I am developing a javafx application. This app communicates with a device and because of that the device jars are not modular and they come with some dll files that are added to the development. Now, it runs perfect on the Netbeans 12.6, but not when I create the installer with the jdk-17 jpackage. I believe I am missing something, but since I am quite new to this jpackage I just don't know how to get it resolved. The following is the structure of the app.

[image]

I want to try running this on the terminal just to see whether it will execute well. What I am getting from the netbeans ant is to try the following;

> Blockquote
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2/bin/java -p C:\Projects\My\App\v3\application-name\dist\application-name.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\controlfx\controlsfx-11.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.4.7\json-smart-2.4.7.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\commons-lang3-3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\commons-dbutils\commons-dbutils\1.7\commons-dbutils-1.7.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.11.0\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\commons-validator\commons-validator\1.7\commons-validator-1.7.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.6.0\hsqldb-2.6.0.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\commons-text-1.9\commons-text-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\uuid\java-uuid-generator\4.0.1\java-uuid-generator-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.0\jackson-annotations-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.0\jackson-core-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.0\jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-csv\2.8.8\jackson-dataformat-csv-2.8.8.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\activation-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\io\github\palexdev\materialfx\11.12.0\materialfx-11.12.0.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jaxrs-2.1\jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\gson\gson-2.8.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-client.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-common.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-server.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jersey-entity-filtering-2.34.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jersey-hk2-2.34.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jersey-media-moxy-2.34.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-container-servlet.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-container-servlet-core.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\hk2-api-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\osgi.core-8.0.0.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.asm-9.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.7.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.7.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql-2.7.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.7.9.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\slf4j\slf4j-api-1.7.35.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\reactfx\reactfx-2.0-M5.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\ikonli\ikonli-core-12.3.0.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\ikonli\ikonli-javafx-12.3.0.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\ikonli\ikonli-materialdesign2-pack-12.3.0.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\ikonli\ikonli-fontawesome5-pack-12.3.0.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\ikonli\ikonli-bootstrapicons-pack-12.3.0.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\zywell_javaPos\JposPrinterJavaPOS.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\zywell_javaPos\jcl.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\zywell_javaPos\jpos113-controls.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\jakarta.activation-api-2.0.1.jar -cp C:\Projects\AntLibrary\controlfx\controlsfx-11.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.4.7\json-smart-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\commons-dbutils\commons-dbutils\1.7\commons-dbutils-1.7.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.6.0\hsqldb-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\commons-validator\commons-validator\1.7\commons-validator-1.7.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\uuid\java-uuid-generator\4.0.1\java-uuid-generator-4.0.1.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\commons-lang3-3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\io\github\palexdev\materialfx\11.12.0\materialfx-11.12.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.11.0\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\commons-text-1.9\commons-text-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.0\jackson-annotations-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.0\jackson-core-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.0\jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Kwesi Aryee.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-csv\2.8.8\jackson-dataformat-csv-2.8.8.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\gson\gson-2.8.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jaxrs-2.1\jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-client.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-common.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-server.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jersey-entity-filtering-2.34.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jersey-hk2-2.34.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jersey-media-moxy-2.34.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-container-servlet.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\jersey-container-servlet-core.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\hk2-api-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\osgi.core-8.0.0.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\jersey2\ext\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.asm-9.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.7.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.7.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql-2.7.9.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.7.9.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\zywell_javaPos\JposPrinterJavaPOS.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\zywell_javaPos\jcl.jar;C:\Projects\AntLibrary\zywell_javaPos\jpos113-controls.jar; -m com.klarysoft.retail
> Blockquote

But then I am getting error with this. Any ideas, I know I am not doing something right. Please I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I've never had to do this, and I'm not sure if it solves your problem, but you can create a jmod which includes native libraries using the `jmod` tool. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jmod.htm

Comment: Not sure on how to do this, but will look at how I can do that, however, I already have jmods included "--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-jmods-17.0.2" \" in the jpackage cmd.

Comment: You need to help us to help you by putting the details of what you've tried and failed with. There are so many reasons why it won't work - for example see other jpackage questions in SO such as [this answer which links to a few common issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456027/java-fx-application-with-jpackage-not-work/70460422#70460422).

Comment: I meant that you may need/want to *create* a jmod to include in the runtime you create with `jpackage` (as well as using the existing JavaFX jmods).

Comment: You may be interested in knowing [what a jmod is and how it differs from a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732915/why-did-java-9-introduce-the-jmod-file-format).  Perhaps you could package your module as a jmod which includes the native libs. Or, perhaps just as a jar with the native libs included as separate resources that you place on the Java native library path using a system property you add to your launch script.

Comment: Yes, I think so and I have to learn how to do this, I'm hoping that the learning curve will not kill my schedule.

Comment: You don't need to make your jars into modules. you just need to ensure your jars + native code libraries are packaged under the `app` directory, then they should be accessible after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX The non-modular approach to use jlink/jpackage described there will also work in your case. I use it, e.g., to include SQLight-JDBC which also includes native libraries.

Comment: OK, will do that, still on the hustle with this

Comment: My project is ant-based and I have some dlls in the project that sits outside the src for it to run. More so I am new to this so I am trying not to break this project